# HighCharts one y axis automatic for each serie

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to use HighCharts to display multiple series accross a same time based X axis. The problem with my data is that it is very disparate. For proper showing I need to create a Y axis for each series with it's own scale.

Like that :

```
yAxis: [
  {
    title: { text: 'Axis 1 with proper scale' }
  },{
    title: { text: 'Axis 2 with proper scale' }
  }
]
```

Then I specify the axis for my series :

```
series: [
{ name: 'Data Serie for axis 1',
  yAxis: 0 ,
  data: [...]
},{
  name: 'Data Serie for axis 2',
  yAxis: 1 ,
  data: [...]
}]
```

Is there a way to do that automatically ? I would like one yAxis automatically created for each serie.

Comment: Did you see this example ? http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes

Comment: Yes sure! In this example the yAxis are created manually ... I would like not having to create them manually. In my ideal one yAxis would be created for each serie.

Comment: I think there's no such option for this. I use highchart for a long time now but I never seen anything so.

Comment: Ok thanks never mind I will do this using asp.

Comment: I agree with Brewal - only manually you can add axis, or loop through all series to generate axis objects.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var yAxis = new Array();
yAxis[0] = opts.yAxis;

for (var i=1; i<opts.series.length; i++) {
    yAxis[i] = $j.extend(true, {}, opts.yAxis);
    //Change offset, color, opposite...
    yAxis[i].title.text = opts.series[i].name;
}
opts.yAxis = yAxis;
```